# Soma em jQuery USD com centavos

Tags: jquery

A seguinte estrutura de formulário:

```
<div class="form-outline mb-4">
    <input type="text" class="form-control money" id="premium" name="premium" placeholder=""
        autocomplete="off">
    <label class="form-label" for="premium">Premium</label>
</div>

<div class="form-outline mb-4">
    <input type="text" class="form-control money" id="comission" name="comission" placeholder="" autocomplete="off">
    <label class="form-label" for="comission">Comission</label>
</div>

<div class="row mb-4">
    <div class="col">
        <div class="form-outline">
            <input type="text" id="feeds_addtional" name="feeds_addtional" class="form-control money" autocomplete="off"
                value="" />
            <label class="form-label" for="feeds_addtional">Fee Addtional</label>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col">
        <div class="form-outline">
            <input type="text" id="cost_total" name="cost_total" class="form-control" autocomplete="off"
                value=""/>
            <label class="form-label" for="cost_total">Cost Total</label> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Representa, neste caso: premium + comission + feeds_addtional = cost_total
Preenchendo automaticamente o total no campo representado.

Os campos de valores são em USD. (1,500,000.95 - um milhão e quinhentos mil dólares com noventa e cinco centavos)

Meu jQuery está da seguinte forma:

```
$(".money").maskMoney();
$(".money").on('keyup', function(e){

    e.preventDefault();          

    let premium             = parseInt(jQuery('#premium').val() != '' ? jQuery('#premium').val().replace(',', '') : 0);
    let comission           = parseInt(jQuery('#comission').val() != '' ? jQuery('#comission').val().replace(',', '') : 0);
    let feeds_addtional     = parseInt(jQuery('#feeds_addtional').val() != '' ? jQuery('#feeds_addtional').val().replace(',', '') : 0);
    var cost_total          = parseFloat(premium + comission + feeds_addtional);
    
    $("#cost_total").val(numberFormat(cost_total)).addClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');               
    
})

function numberFormat(v){
    return parseFloat(v).toLocaleString("en-US", { style: "currency" , currency:"USD", minimumFractionDigits: 2, maximumFractionDigits: 2}).replace('$', '');
}
```

Porém, no momento de somar, não está somando os centavos para totalizar.

```
Resultado esperado:  
Premium: 200,000.02  
Comission: 100,500.05 
Fee: 15,000.96
Cost: 315,501.03
```

Como modificar para que funcione da maneira correta?

Answer (score 0):

A função `parseInt` faz a conversão de uma string para um dado numérico do tipo **Inteiro**. Tipos inteiros não tem casas decimais e por isso vc perde os centavos.

Para obter os centavos de uma string, vc deve usar `parseFloat` q diferente d `parseInt`, retorna um dado do tipo `float` que possui casas decimais.

Outro problema é que vc está substituindo a vírgula `,` da string por um espaço vazio ``. Ao invés de fazer isso, vc pode substituir por um ponto `.`, dessa forma o `parseFloat` vai conseguir fazer a conversão sem perder as casas decimais.

Aqui um exemplo de uma função q vc pode utilizar p/ simplificar tudo isso:

```js
function floatValueFrom(selector) {
  const value = (jQuery(selector).val() ?? '').replace(',', '.')
  return parseFloat(value)
}
```

Comment: Jan, neste caso, eu estou trabalhando com a moeda USD, por isso eu subst o ",", por nada. No caso ( 15,000.00 )

Comment: A moeda não importa. Se vc só remover a vírgula, também não vai dar certo. Basta substituir por `.` q o `parseFloat` consegue converter p/ float direto.